# how to set onListItemClick for listview in android

Tags: android

hi
i need to do onListItemClick event for list view. i did the following but did not work. i paste my code and logcat. please help me. error is: (java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list')

```
public class MyListView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
//    @Override
    ListView list1;
    private String array[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android","item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" }; 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));        

    }
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String pen = o.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the pen: " + " " + pen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

my log cat file:

```
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sai.ui.listview/com.sai.ui.listview.MyListView}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:236)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:321)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1631)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at com.sai.ui.listview.MyListView.onCreate(MyListView.java:21)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1132)
04-19 18:12:36.021: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5162):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
```

my main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:stackFromBottom="true"
 >
 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageview1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="50px"
 android:background="@drawable/applicationbar"
 android:layout_x="0px"
 android:layout_y="0px"
>
</ImageView>
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textview1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="50px"
 android:text="TextView"
 android:layout_x="0px"
 android:layout_y="55px"
 >
 </TextView>
 <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10px" 
 android:layout_marginRight="10px"
 android:layout_marginTop="35px" 
 android:layout_marginBottom="40px"
 android:paddingLeft="0px"
 android:paddingRight="0px" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListActivity` requires `ListView` with id `android.R.id.list`. It provides you with additional methods to manage your `ListView` and it's adapter. So you should not use code like

```
list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
```

use
 `list1 = getListView()`
instead.

However, you could go as Kartik suggested, means you can use a regular `Activity` instead of `ListActivity` and use your originally posted code.

Answer (score 11):

```
 public class MyListView extends Activity
```

intead of

```
 public class MyListView extends ListActivity
```

and for listening the item clicks, use this :

```
  list1.setOnItemClickListener(
        new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                         //Take action here.
                 }
            }
     );
```

So your complete source code would be like this :

```
 public class MyListView extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

  ListView list1;
private String array[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android","item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" }; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));        


list1.setOnItemClickListener(
        new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Object o = list1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String pen = o.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have chosen the pen: " + " " + pen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }   
        }       
);

 }
}
```

**Edited as per ernazm answer:**

if you want to use the

```
   public class MyListView extends ListActivity
```

you must remove

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

As i see there is an drawable in your xml file 
you can still go with this for adding the image header using listview.addHeader():

```
 Resources res=getResources();
 Drawable d1=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage);
 textview.setBackgroundDrawable(d1);
 listview.addHeaderView(tv1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you **must** make sure that your your `ListView` has this id: `@android:id/list` (you currently are using `ListView01`). In fact, that's what the error is trying to telling you:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML, change the id of `ListView0` to just `list`.

Comment: i change in main.xml as ListView01 to just list and list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); again i get same error.

Comment: hi i paste my xml by editing my question(at last) please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In you xml layout file called main.xml, it appears you have a list with id ListView01. This should be hanged to android.R.id.list. So in your xml...

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
 ...
 />
```

Also, you don't need to create a reference to it to set the adapter, you can just call the setListAdapter method for ListActivity.

Comment: hi how to use @android:id/list in my activity list1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id....) i do not get it from R.id. please help me.

Answer (score -2):

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(item[position] + " is clicked.");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    builder.show();
}
```